# Facebook seems to randomly have appeared in my project

Tags: ios, facebook, cocoapods, fbsdk, fbsdkloginkit

I have noticed in my logs that I get the following. **Which pod are they a part of?**

> : Please set a value for FacebookAutoLogAppEventsEnabled. Set the flag to TRUE if you want to collect app install, app launch and in-app purchase events automatically. To request user consent before collecting data, set the flag value to FALSE, then change to TRUE once user consent is received. Learn more: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-events/getting-started-app-events-ios#disable-auto-events.
>
> :
>   You haven't set a value for FacebookAdvertiserIDCollectionEnabled. Set
>   the flag to TRUE if you want to collect Advertiser ID for better
>   advertising and analytics results. To request user consent before
>   collecting data, set the flag value to FALSE, then change to TRUE once
>   user consent is received. Learn more:
>   https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-events/getting-started-app-events-ios#disable-auto-events.

Here are my pods:

```
pod 'Firebase'
pod 'Firebase/Firestore'
pod 'Firebase/Storage'
pod 'Firebase/Core'
pod 'Firebase/Auth'
pod 'Firebase/Database'
pod 'FirebaseUI'
pod 'SDWebImage'
pod 'Mapbox-iOS-SDK', '~> 4.9'
pod 'Firebase/Analytics'
pod 'Firebase/Messaging'
pod 'Nuke', '~> 7.0'
```

I have not been able to find which one it is a part of if any. **How can I remove them?**

In my pod's folder I see them here:
[image]

Comment: Since this is about user tracking/ gathering analytics data, first guess would be that it’s part of  `Firebase/Analytics` …

Comment: Look at the Podfile.lock?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Facebook SDK is a [dependency of FirebaseUI](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-iOS/blob/master/FirebaseUI.podspec#L107). You can choose the specific subspecs of FirebaseUI to exclude it, instead of installing all of the subspecs by not specifying subspecs.

To find out why any particular dependency is added to your project, see the `Podfile.lock` file.

Comment: where can I find this file? Also, What does firebase UI do? I dont remember adding it. Also, could this facebook dependency be dangerous? I know it may seem crazy but based off of experience I know how far companies can go to get data on a market or competitors...

Comment: The Podfile.lock file is generated in the same directory as the Podfile and xcworkspace.

Comment: See https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-iOS for info about FirebaseUI